# A static variable in static class asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a static class Data:

```
 public static class Data
    {
        public static SqlConnection connexion;


        public static bool  Connect()
        {
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder["Initial Catalog"] = "Upload";
                builder["Data Source"] = "base";
                builder["integrated Security"] = true;
                string connexionString = builder.ConnectionString;
                connexion = new SqlConnection(connexionString);
                try { connexion.Open(); return true; }
                catch { return false; }

        }
        public static  void Disconnect()
        {
            if (connexion != null) connexion.Close();
            connexion = null;
        }

 }
```

in an the action Home :

```
  public ActionResult Home()
        {
            Data.Connect();
            if (CompteModels.Connected)
            {
                ArrayList model = new ArrayList();

                ClientModels clients = new ClientModels();
                model.AddRange(clients.Client_List());

                AdminModels admins = new AdminModels();
                model.AddRange(admins.Admin_List());


                return View(model);
            }

            else return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

the client class:

```
 public List<ClientModels> Client_List()
        {
            List<ClientModels> l = new List<ClientModels>();

            using (Data.connexion)
            {

                string queryString = @"select Login, Password, Mail, Name, Tentatives from Compte where User_type_id in ( select Id from User_type where Fonction = 'Client')";

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, Data.connexion);


                try
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


                    do
                    {

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            ClientModels admin = new ClientModels { Login = reader.GetString(0), Password = reader.GetString(1), Mail = reader.GetString(2), Name = reader.GetString(3), Tentatives = reader.GetInt32(4)  };
                            l.Add(admin);


                        }
                    } while (reader.NextResult());

                    return l;



                }
                catch { return null; }

            }
```

For the function `AdminList`, the implementation is the same like `Client_List` but in the class `Admin`.

The problem is in the static variable `connexion` : in the first function `Client_List` its value is correct and i get the list of the clients , but it's become `null` in the second function despite it is a static variable in static class !!!

What is the reason of this alteration ? How can i fix it?

Comment: Trying to hold a `SqlConnection` open in a static field is probably a bad idea for a number of reasons.  Most likely it's `null` because it's being disposed of after its first use.  Just create a new `SqlConnection` when you need it, and release it right away.  Don't try to hold on to SQL resources indefinitely.

Comment: @David  +1, a very, very bad idea.

Comment: `using (Data.connexion)` - as soon as your first consumer uses it, the connection closes and is disposed.  As David says, don't keep your connection around - open it when you need it, close it when you're done, and don't try to implement your own connection "pool".

Comment: This question needs a better title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're either setting `connexion` to `null` somewhere or not initializing it before you use it.

Most likely, one class is calling `Disconnect` which sets `connexion` to null, while another class assumes it's not null and tries to use it.

As mentioned in the comments, keeping a static reference to a resource like a `SqlConnection` is not a good idea.  If you want to re-use code you can create a static *function* that returns a *new* `SqlConnection` instance and make the *connection string* static, but having a static reference to a connection that's share across the entire web site will give you more problems that it's worth (as you're already seeing).

One way to do it in a static function would be:

```
public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder["Initial Catalog"] = "Upload";
    builder["Data Source"] = "base";
    builder["integrated Security"] = true;
    string connexionString = builder.ConnectionString;
    connexion = new SqlConnection(connexionString);

    return connexion; 
}
```

Your client code would then look something like:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = Data.GetConnection())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea, as others have already mentioned.

You should simply create and open a connection when needed, and dispose it afterwards:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{    
    connection.Open();
    // ... now use it
}
```

Of course, there are other patterns, that hide this mechanism, but that might be overkill in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your using statement disposes of the connexion using the IDisposable interface

```
 public List<ClientModels> Client_List()
 {
      List<ClientModels> l = new List<ClientModels>();

      using (Data.connexion) <--- here
}
```

Change this to create a new connection

```
 public List<ClientModels> Client_List()
 {
      List<ClientModels> l = new List<ClientModels>();

      using (var connection = Data.CreateConnexion())
}
```

similar to this

```
 public static class Data
 {
     public static SqlConnection CreateConnection()
     {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder["Initial Catalog"] = "Upload";
            builder["Data Source"] = "base";
            builder["integrated Security"] = true;
            string connexionString = builder.ConnectionString;
            var connexion = new SqlConnection(connexionString);
            connexion.Open(); 
            return connexion; 

     }
 }
```